# Assigning ng-model to ng-repeat item

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui

we have a scenario where i need to repeat the `<li>` item and we need dynamic model in that to write click event.

```
 <ul class="flights trip1-list" ig-init="trip1_fare = 0">
    <li ng-repeat="data in flt_det" ng-click="addUp($event)" ng-model="***">
                            <div class="flight-icons"></div>
                            <div class="flight-details">
                                <div class="time">{{data.depart_time|date:'HH:mm'}}</div>
                                <div class="name">{{data.flight_name}} </div>
                                <div class="duration">{{(data.arrival_time - data.depart_time)}}</div>
                            </div></li>...</ul>
```

How can we get dynamic model in this case and can i get the value from the json itself i.e 'data' here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the repeated item, data.

EDITED:

Put this in the controller:

```
// private variable for storing watch functions to unbind when the
// controller is destroyed to reduce watchers & prevent memory leaks
var unbindFns = [];

function bindWatchers() {
  angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
    var unbind = $scope.$watch(item.fooBar, function() {
      // do stuff
    });

    unbindFns.push(unbind);
  });
}

function unbindWatchers() {
  angular.forEach(unbindFns, function(fn) {
    fn();
  });
}

$scope.$on('$destroy', unbindWatchers);
```

Comment: but that i can use in the child elements not on the <li> elements

Comment: Child elements of the ```<li>``` tag? In your example you don't have children defined. If you did you would be able to access the data attribute in the child elements.

Comment: plz find the edited code and i want to trigger an event on the <li> element and based on some data of this some event will trigger.So i want some model on <li>

Comment: im sorry i dont understand what you're asking. are you saying you want to listen for an event on a model in a collection? If these are CRUD events on a collection, you can use $watchCollection. If you're talking about listening for a specific event on each item in the collection, for example, ```data.fooBar()```,  then look at my edited answer.